# grails 4 call a namespaced taglib from another taglib

Tags: grails

How can I access a taglib wwith a different namespace from another taglib in grails 4?
I can't seem to cross call.

Here's an example

```
 class MyLibTagLib{

  static namespace="myLib"

  def fancy={attrs->
      ....
  }
}

import app.lib.MyLibTagLib
class CallerTagLib{

  //in the default 'g' namespace

  //def myLib //injection fails

  def fancyText={attrs->
      //fails
      out << myLib.fancy(attrs)
      //also fails
      grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('app.lib.MyLibTagLib')
  }
}
```

Comment: `def myLib //injection fails` - Injection fails there because there is no bean named `myLib`.  The bean name would be `demo.MyLibTagLib` (replace "demo" with whatever your package name is).  That said, there is no good reason to inject a tag bean into another tag bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problematic behavior that you describe.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tagquestion.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tagquestion/blob/9a389f957c8327d071e55a131b9c8a83663a6f3e/grails-app/taglib/demo/MyLibTagLib.groovy

```
package demo

class MyLibTagLib {
    static namespace="myLib"

    def fancy={attrs->
        out << 'Something Fancy'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tagquestion/blob/9a389f957c8327d071e55a131b9c8a83663a6f3e/grails-app/taglib/demo/CallerTagLib.groovy

```
package demo

class CallerTagLib {

    def fancyText = { attrs ->
        out << myLib.fancy(attrs)
    }
}
```

The main `index.gsp` at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tagquestion/blob/9a389f957c8327d071e55a131b9c8a83663a6f3e/grails-app/views/index.gsp#L56 invokes `<g:fancyText/>` and that works.

Comment: dang. The only difference I see is that my taglibs are from 2 different packages. Thanks for the demo. I'll look at it and see what the difference is.

Comment: If you can share a simple sample project like the one I created and in that project can demonstrate the issue, I am happy to take a look at it.  If you think it is a bug in the framework, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues and we will address whatever the issue is.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It was indeed the package difference that was the key to tracing down the problem. grails works as expected, though I might have a complaint about groovy's compile time checking.

Comment: "I might have a complaint about groovy's compile time checking" - I don't see what the compiler is doing here that is incorrect.  What would the complaint be?  Thanks for the feedback and we will look into it.

Comment: "It was indeed the package difference that was the key to tracing down the problem." - I am trying to chase it down and I cannot.  After https://github.com/jeffbrown/tagquestion/commit/61f45a3f767576e6ca2ed3a20ef8e21cb96d4c5b the dispatch still works.  I will keep trying.  If you can share a project which demonstrates the issue that would be helpful.  If it is broken, I would like to get it fixed.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2782001 Would you be willing to send a PR to that repo I created which includes whatever combo of factors it takes to reproduce the misbehavior?  Having that would be helpful.  Thanks for any help.  I appreciate your time.